# FPC does not define CPU386 symbol for 64-bit processors

Tags: delphi, fpc

The next application

```
program Project1;

{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$mode delphi}
{$ENDIF}

begin
  {$IFDEF CPU386}
    Writeln('CPU386');
  {$ENDIF}
  Readln;
end.
```

produce different output in Delphi(XE) and FPC(2.6.2) on my system (Win7 64 bit, CPU intel core i3). Delphi outputs `CPU386` string, FPC does not.

Seems like FPC does not define `CPU386` symbol for my CPU (see [the list of FPC defines](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progap7.html)); it defines `CPUX86_64` symbol instead.

So far I am using the next workaround:

```
{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$IFNDEF CPU386}
    {$IFDEF CPUX86_64}
      {$DEFINE CPU386}
    {$ENDIF}
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Yes. Delphi should not have chosen them incompatible to almost decade old existing FPC defines. Worse, they were even using FPC at the time (XE2). Please file a bug with Embarcadero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is as expected. The `CPU386` conditional is for 32 bit Intel x86 targets. The `CPUX86_64` conditional is for 64 bit Intel x64 targets.

When you compile your program with the 64 bit Delphi compiler, it does not produce any output either. Because the `CPU386` conditional is not defined for the 64 bit Delphi compiler either.

It is incorrect to do this:

```
{$IFDEF CPUX86_64}
  {$DEFINE CPU386}
{$ENDIF}
```

The `CPU386` means that the target architecture is 32 bit Intel x86. And 64 bit Intel x64 is not.

The Delphi documentation for predefined conditionals is here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)#Predefined_Conditionals

It lists the following under the CPU heading:

- CPUARM
- CPU386
- CPUX86
- CPUX64

For 32 bit x86 targets Delphi and FPC both define `CPU386`. For 64 bit x64 targets Delphi defined `CPUX64` and FPC defines `CPUX86_64`.

If you need to use common conditionals across shared source code then you will likely need to do some extra work. Suppose that you settle on `CPUX86` and `CPUX64`. Then you would include this:

```
{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$IFNDEF CPU386}
    {$DEFINE CPUX86}
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFNDEF CPUX86_64}
    {$DEFINE CPUX64}
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Just an additional note: the 64-bit Delphi compiler won't define `CPUX86_64` either (at least according to the documentation): it uses `CPUX64` instead, so there is still an incompatibility.

Comment: thank you, could not check it having no 64-bit Delphi.

Comment: I think the doc link that I included is useful for those of us that don't have all the compilers. I only have dcc32 and dcc64.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to look in FPC's "fpc -va  output to see what a (32-bit) FPC would define on i386: (2.6.0)

```
[0.002] Macro defined: CPU86
[0.002] Macro defined: CPU87
[0.002] Macro defined: CPU386
[0.002] Macro defined: CPUI386
[0.002] Macro defined: CPU32
```

A 64-bit compiler defines: (2.7.1, didn't have a release version at hand)

```
[0.004] Macro defined: CPUX86_64
[0.004] Macro defined: CPUAMD64
[0.004] Macro defined: CPU64
[0.004] Macro defined: CPUX64
```

It is a pity that Delphi didn't choose compatible defines. Since the x86_64 architecture has been renamed several time, FPC defines several.

Note btw that **CPU32 and CPU64 are for general 32/64-bit switching**. Use this for anything that affects only pointer size but is not x86 specific. While originally mostly  to abstract between Intel and PowerPC, with **64-bit ARM** coming this because important again.

The cpui386 and cpux86_64 for changes that really target a specific processor.

The manual for these defines is [here](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progap7.html)